# how to overlap monitors on gnome/wayland (stock ubuntu22.04)

Tags: gnome, wayland, wacom, gnome-settings-daemon

I am attempting to use a "drawing tablet" with my 22.04 laptop.  The laptop is ~2k resolution (2256x1504), and the graphics tablet is 1920x1080.    I wish to have the graphics tablet display a subsection (eg duplicate the pixels) of the laptops screen.  For example, center the graphics tablet over the "center" of the screen, displaying part of a Gimp window where I'm drawing - with the whole gimp window visible on the main 2k display.

For clarity, this is an LCD type drawing tablet - basically just a 2nd monitor w/ a ~wacom digitizer bonded on top.  If the drawing tablet and laptop were the same resolution, or possibly even just close, I could just `mirror` them.

I have tried editing `~/.config/monitors.xml` and adjusting the `x`,`y` position of the tablet display, and restarting the session (log in/out), but there is no effect.

How can I move what's displayed on the lower-resolution external tablet to be "over" a subset my main display?